# Activity context.this cannot be resolved to a variable (inside Toast)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclicklistener, android-toast

I'm trying to insert a `button` to rate app in my `activity`, with a `toast` for if market isn't found. But I'm getting a "`Context cannot be resolved to a variable`" on Activity.this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
try {
    startActivity(goToMarket);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Couldn't launch the market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I've also tried:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't launch the market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But then I get Multiple markers at this line
    - The method `makeText(Context, CharSequence, int)` in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments `(new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)`

I've made a simple `button toast` the same way (without `try`/`catch`) before, and then it worked fine.. 
What have I done wrong?

Comment: use this one Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't launch the market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! 
-It did the trick. 
I tried getApplicationContext() before and it didn't work, but now it Did! -I must have done something wrong the last time.. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class is extending with Activity means use like this

```
Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, "Couldn't launch the market",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**or**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't launch the market",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If your Class is extending with Fragment means use like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Couldn't launch market",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! 
-It did the trick. 
I tried getApplicationContext() before and it didn't work, but now it Did! -I must have done something wrong the last time.. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't launch the market", Toast.LEGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't launch the market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
            startActivity(goToMarket);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't launch the market", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Hope this will help you...